# Custom Attribute for the route

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I want to create a custom attribute, for a parameter in my route. I can't use a "ParameterBindingAttribute"

Before the "Do something", i want to verify the parameter myVar

How to do this?

```
[Route("{myVar}/TOTO")]
public IHttpActionResult Get([myAttribute]int myVar)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please detail your question to make it clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an action filter that will inspect the values.

```
[VerifyMyVar]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int myVar)
{
    // TODO
}

public class VerifyMyVar : HttpActionFilterAttribute
{
    ...
}
```

if you want more specific validation you can have the filter inspect the MethodInfo, and do something more specific with the code inside [myAttribute].